# Nginxplus docker build is failing with 403 Forbidden error for Centos 7

Tags: docker, nginx, centos

I am trying to build and nginx plus docker image with centos 7 .Below is the Dockerfile I am using.

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER NGINX Docker Maintainers "x@x.com"
RUN yum install -y wget

# Copy certificate and key to the build context
ADD nginx-repo.crt /etc/ssl/nginx/
ADD nginx-repo.key /etc/ssl/nginx/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Get other files required for installation
RUN wget -q -O /etc/ssl/nginx/CA.crt https://cs.nginx.com/static/files/CA.crt
RUN wget -q -O /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx-plus-7.repo https://cs.nginx.com/static/files/nginx-plus-7.repo

# Install NGINX Plus
RUN yum install -y nginx-plus

# forward request logs to Docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I have nginx-repo.crt and nginx-repo.key with me for the developer license. When I do docker build with this I am getting the below error.

```
Step 10/14 : RUN yum install -y nginx-plus
 ---> Running in 4e8ccb452b81
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.mit.edu
 * extras: mirror.umd.edu
 * updates: centos.servint.com
https://plus-pkgs.nginx.com/centos/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article

https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.



 One of the configured repositories failed (nginx-plus repo),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=nginx-plus ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable nginx-plus
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=nginx-plus

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=nginx-plus.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from nginx-plus: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://plus-pkgs.nginx.com/centos/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y nginx-plus' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Couldn't figure out what is the issue. The steps before

```
RUN yum install -y nginx-plus
```

are all succesfull

**UPDATE**

Issue was fixed after replacing the repo path and changing to certificate installation. Updated Docker file

```
FROM centos:centos7
MAINTAINER NGINX Docker Maintainers "docker-maint@nginx.com"
RUN yum install -y wget
# Download certificate and key from the customer portal (https://cs.nginx.com)
# and copy to the build context

ADD nginx-repo.crt /etc/ssl/nginx/
ADD nginx-repo.key /etc/ssl/nginx/

RUN  yum install ca-certificates

#Get other files required for installation
RUN  wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d https://cs.nginx.com/static/files/nginx-plus-7.4.repo

#Install NGINX Plus
RUN yum install -y nginx-plus

#forward request logs to Docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the repo is not available, as per [NGINX Docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-plus/), you can try the latest nginx-plus-repo:

```
sudo wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d https://cs.nginx.com/static/files/nginx-plus-7.4.repo
```

So your Dockerfile will look like:

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER NGINX Docker Maintainers "x@x.com"
RUN yum install -y wget

# Copy certificate and key to the build context
ADD nginx-repo.crt /etc/ssl/nginx/
ADD nginx-repo.key /etc/ssl/nginx/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Get other files required for installation
RUN yum install ca-certificates
RUN sudo wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d https://cs.nginx.com/static/files/nginx-plus-7.4.repo

# Install NGINX Plus
RUN yum install -y nginx-plus

# forward request logs to Docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: "RUN wget -q -O /etc/ssl/nginx/CA.crt https://cs.nginx.com/static/files/CA.crt" instead of this line , have to use  "RUN  yum install ca-certificates" since Nginxplus now uses a certificate signed by Global Sign